# R Script Tab Recovery

Tags: r, rscript

I'm rather green with R and Rstudio, and accidentally closed R script tabs that were open without saving them. I thought that all scripts were saved together within one file, but apparently only one of the scripts was saved. Now when I open that R file, it just opens the one script and not the other script tabs. I had hundreds of hours worth of code in these scripts for my thesis. Is there anyway to recover these script tabs???? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you spent hundreds of hours on a script you never bothered to explicitly save?

Comment: the scripts always opened when I opened the saved one..I didn't realize that I never saved the other ones individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install R Studio, you should have installed R first. Try closing R Studio and just opening R; see if you get a `Previously saved workspace restored` and all your work is still there or not.

Comment: Yup this worked for me.  Thanks for the quick response.  I am saving each script file individually from now on.